# Asking about os.path.basename(root) in python

Tags: python

I want to understand why every time I print out my `os.path.basename(root)` from a sub-directory folder, it always shows an empty list at the beginner of the list. Is there any way to avoid this?

**My data folder:**

```
dir_1:
-subdir_1:
  -img1.jpg
-subdir_2:
  -img2.jpg
```

**My code:**

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    print(os.path.basename(root))
```

**My output:**

```
['','subdir_1','subdir_2']
```

**My Expected output:**

```
['subdir_1','subdir_2']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=os%20path%20basename#os.path.basename) explains this:

> Return the base name of pathname path. This is the second element of the pair returned by passing path to the function split(). Note that the result of this function is different from the Unix basename program; where basename for '/foo/bar/' returns 'bar', the basename() function returns an empty string ('').

Comment: so is there a way that my output is ['subdir_1','subdir_2'] not  ['','subdir_1','subdir_2']?

Comment: You'll see different results depending on `path` ending with `/` or not.

Comment: No, it doesn't. This is only true for pathnames ending with a slash. However, this is not what `os.walk(path)` returns (at least not for macOS). @sharee Can you please provide the output if you just use `print(root)` ?

Comment: @Rumo if I print(root), this is the result dir_1/ ; dir_1/sub_dir1 ; dir_1/sub_dir2

Comment: By the way, I have figured it out. Thanks everyone

Comment: Then @Frederico S is right. Strange however that this behaves differently on different operating systems. Which OS are you using?

Comment: On Windows 10 using `os.walk('C:/temp')` I get back the same result (without a trailing slash) and so `basename` gives me `"temp"`. Using `os.walk('C:/temp/')` I get back the same result (with the trailing slash) and so `basename` returns `""`.